# how to prevent MVC action and use javascript function

Tags: javascript, c#, model-view-controller

**Form:**

```
<form asp-action="Edit" method="post">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a id="informacje-ogolne-tab" class="nav-link tab-buttons">Informacje ogólne</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a id="kategorie-tab" class="nav-link tab-buttons">Kategorie</a>
            </li>
        </ul>

        <div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
            <div id="informacje-ogolne-content" class="tab-pane fade">
                    @await Component.InvokeAsync("ProductEditGeneralInfoTab", new { product = Model })
            </div>
            <div id="kategorie-content" class="tab-pane fade">
                    @await Component.InvokeAsync("ProductEditCategoryTab", new { productId = Model.ProductId })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="text-left">
            <button class="btn btn-primary mt-1" type="submit">Zapisz</button>
        </div>
    </form>
```

**ProductEditCategoryTab**

```
@model ValueTypeListBoxViewModel

@Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.SelectedValue, Model.Values, new { size = 15 })
<div class="text-left">
    <button id="add" class="btn btn-primary mt-1">Dodaj</button>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Inside script tag I want to add javascript logic to add, remove logic from one listbox to another.
But when I press 'Dodaj' it's run the same action as 'Zapisz' button. In this form there will be probably more buttons and the only one that has to run the action should be 'Zapisz'

**Question:**

How to prevent run action when i press 'Dodaj' and work by javascript/jquery.

Comment: You can stop a button from submitting by setting it's type to button: `<button type="button">`. It defaults to submit.

Comment: thanks! its working